# How can I take a scrolling screenshot within an iframe?

Tags: osx, screenshot

Our website is designed such that the text scrolls within an iframe while the background (an image) remains static.

Is there any tool in the market that will help me to take the screenshot of the entire page, including the entire iframe content on my Mac?

Comment: Dosn't the inbuilt support work?  https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201361

Comment: I don't think it's possible because if it captures both the main frame and the iframe, the iframe will 'ruin' the look of the main frame, doesn't it?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know for certain that these will work the way you intend but [Ember](http://realmacsoftware.com/ember/) claims to take screenshots of entire web pages. I'm not sure how it works with iframed pages.

If it is not critical to get a screenshot of the content of the iframe with that background image you can use Firefox to open the iframe in a separate tab and then get a screenshot of it or, if it still scrolls, Print it and choose a PDF program as the printer (you'll need Adobe Acrobat, CutePDFWriter, or something similar to have that option).

If it IS critical to have all the other page content visible along with the iframed content, you may need to add a CSS change to the PDF print option. It may be possible to edit the print styles of your web site so that the iframe is taller only when the page is going to be printed. That way it will look normal when just viewing it but will show all the iframed content when it's being printed (or printed to a PDF program).

Answer (score 1):

You can't, because they are seperate documents. The only way to achieve that would be to manipulate the page's code before printing so that the iframe was bigger, but this would have to be done by hand since the iframe's width and height may not be the only page elements actually limiting it's sizing. For example the iframe could be inside several other div tags that have fixed sizes. You'd also need to know the height and width of the content being shown in the iframe so you'd know how big to make the iframe's new size.

Screenshot Of Printing iFrame Contents In Firefox:

[image]

However you can print the iframe's content on it's own in Mozilla Firefox. Just right-click on the iframe, choose "This Frame", and then select "Print Frame".